# Send multiple images over TCP?

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I am working with `Android` and `.Net(C#)`. I want to send some image (png) from `Android` to PC via `TCP socket` but PC always receives only 1 image. Please help me!

**Android code** (This code is inside a method, and I call it many times):

```
    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    File f = new File(filePath);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```

**C# code** (I also call this code many times too, to get image):

```
    Socket s = 
        new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, 
        ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPAddress.Text), 8002));
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(new NetworkStream(s));
```

UPDATE: My android application will take screen shot time by time, then transfer to PC agent to view. So that, It's inconvenience when create a separated socket for each captured image. Right?

Comment: Do you mean that you create/establish new socket connections for sending each images ?

Comment: Maybe you could send your images with http POST and be simple and lightweight.

Comment: I don't want to create new socket for each image. I want to use only one socket to transfer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current design may probably handle one image only.
Please design your protocol format.
For example,

no. of images n (4-bytes), length 1 (4-bytes), image data 1 (N1-bytes), length 2, image data 2 (N2-bytes), ..., length n (4-bytes), image data n (Nn-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

You're only writing one image to the stream at a time and closing it.  Depending on how the android is prompted to send images you might be starting the process over and only writing the same first image again and again.

You could try linquize's solution and make one large response that you send or you could try adding a variable of some sort telling the android which image to write.  Then you should be able to write each image as a separate write.

Comment: I just close  outputSteam. I keep socket connection alive. Is this a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the PC code is trying to read everything in the socket and it's only getting the one write.  If you keep the socket open and write from the android, then read from the PC, and then repeat it should work.  Have you tried something like that?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh You aren't keeping the socket connection alive. Closing either the input or the output stream closes the other stream and the socket, which in turn closes the connection.